# Issue installing perf/system tap on kernel 3.1

Tags: linux-kernel, glibc, utility, perf, systemtap

I have custom linux on kernel 3.1 with glibc 2.14 . Now when i try to install perf/systemtap it ask for glibc2.15, I am not able to remove the existing glibc2.14 as it has dependencies linked to it.Is there a way i can install perf/system tap . Hope i am able to explain myself clearly.

Details:
perf requires libnewt & libslang which requires glibc2.15 , hence i am stuck in a deadlock.

Comment: Please identify your distribution, the mechanism by which systemtap appears to asks for glibc 2.15, and the detailed reason for not being able to upgrade your glibc to 2.15.

Comment: systemtap only requires a debug kernel to be installed. Try running stap-prep.

Comment: Tom-100:/root # stap-prep
If 'stap-prep' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
This is what i got when i tried stap-prep.@fche - what you mean be identifying the distribution.We have a custom linux which uses glibc 2.14 only, hence i am unable to remove it, can you guys let me know any alternative, i am stuck.

Comment: any reply’s on this??